# need a script to split and assign values Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to separate and reassign values in a variable. What I have is

```
#&first=1&second=2
```

can anyone help with a script that will separate and assign this values to another variable so it would be like

```
var first= val.(first);
var second= val.(second);
```

I am new to jquery so I am not even sure if I am using the correct syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var val = "#&first=1&second=2";

var first = gup(val, "first");
var second = gup(val, "second");


function gup(str, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(str);
    if (results == null) return "";
    else return results[1];
}
```

Checkout the example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WxnJq/

Answer (score 3):

Here's the one that breaks down the GET variables in to key/value pairs, which I believe is what you're after: http://snipplr.com/view/12208/javascript-url-parser/

Also, you can take a look at [`parseURI`](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri), a javascript function that can dissect a URL with GET parameters and grab sections.

*Sorry for being quick to post, I thought I found the right function the first time.*

Comment: Actually, hold on--you want the GET variables. This just breaks sections. Bear with me, looking for the right function...

Comment: Hey Brad, works but a little to long. @kmb385 post was perfect for what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has no builtin way of dealing with querystrings, so I use a plugin for this. [You can get it here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object), works great.